# two row header conversion

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[click here to see the design - two-row header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3psWm.png)

I am confused to develop this type of header design, 1st row 2 elements centered logo and right side icons, second row have the menu, how can perfectly code the html and css, also how it should work in responsive menu, please help me.

https://github.com/anasrhmankk/interview-task.git

this here i added link of the conversion i done, its not proper coding,
guid me
thank you

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Logo
              
                
              
              
                
                    
                      Home
                    
                    
                      Shop
                    
                    
                      Client Diaries
                    
                    
                      About us
                    
                    
                        Appointment
                      
                      
                        Sale
                      
                  
                
                  
                    
                        search
                    
                  
                  
                    user
                  
                  
                    cart
                        0

```
          </div>
        </div>
      </nav>


</header>
```

```css
.navbar-brand {
    position: absolute;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}

li.nav-item.cart {
    position: relative;
}
.mini-cart-count {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    background: #ED1C2A;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
}
header .navbar-nav .nav-link {
    color: #151515;
}
.menu-bar-btm {
    margin-top: 130px;
    position: relative;
    display: inline-flex;
    width: 100%;
}
ul.navbar-nav.basket {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -120px;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    flex-direction: unset;
}
ul.navbar-nav.basket li {
    float: left;
}
.menu-bar-btm ul.navbar-nav {
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 17px;
    column-gap: 20px;
}
```

Comment: can you provide the code you have done here, not a zip elsewhere that can contain anything

Comment: @RichardMuvirimi hi, here i added the html css code

Comment: still there is no html, we need to see what you have done so we can start there not do it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

The layout [codepen](https://codepen.io/JaredSpb/pen/dyJMdMX) without images, paddings, etc.

```html
<header>
  <a class='logo'>Logo here</a>
  <aside>
    <a>Search</a>
    <a>Login</a>
    <a>Cart</a>
  </aside>
  <nav>
    <a>Home</a>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>
    <a>...</a>    
  </nav>  
</header>
```

```css
header{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
header > aside{
  flex: 1 0 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  background: lightblue;
}
header > aside a{
  margin: 0 1em;
}
header::before{
  content: '';
  background: pink;
  flex: 1 0 0;
}

header > nav{
  flex: 1 0 100%;
  display: flex;  
  justify-content: center;
}
header > nav a{
  margin: 1em;
  padding: .2em .5em;
  background: lightgreen;  
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, i understand you used just flexbox to arrange, i didnt understand how it really worked this way.